# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've just started a MVC 4 project and I cant figure out why the JQuery is broken:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<h2>List</h2>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

The links in the header works just fine. I get this error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

Comment: try to update jquery. Actual version is 1.9.1

Comment: Why are you including the library twice?

Comment: You may want to check that the jquery ui you are downloading is the full library and not maybe a custom download with only some widgets...

Answer (score -1):

Insert this code before using **datetimepiker** or **datepicker** function

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
```